# Understanding HashMap and IdentityHashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

I am creating 3 objects of same class: A,B,rB. Here rB is referencing to B. And values of A and B are equal. I had overrided equals method where I am comparing the values.

So

> A.equals(B), A.equals(rB) and B.equals(rB) is true. But A != B, A !=
>   rB and B == rB.

Now I am putting A,B,rB in HashMap, say hm, and IdentityHashMap, say ihm.

```
    hm.put(A, "1");
    hm.put(B, "2");
    hm.put(rB, "3");

    ihm.put(A, "1");
    ihm.put(B, "2");
    ihm.put(rB, "3");
```

Since I am not storing null, so `hm.get(A)` should return 3, `hm.get(B)` should return 3 and `hm.get(rB)` should return 3.
Similarly, `ihm.get(A)` should return 1, `ihm.get(B)` should return 3 and `ihm.get(rB)` should return 3.

As per the java docs, IdentityHashMap does k1 == k2 while HashMap does k1.equals(k2) , if k1 and k2 are not null.

So why `hm.get(A)` is returning 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say that you overrode `equals`, but did you override `hashCode` as well? If not, then this is likely to be the cause of the behaviour you are seeing.

`HashMap` will only use `equals` when two keys have the same hash code, so it is essential that whenever you override `equals` you also override `hashCode` and vice versa.

Comment: I printed hashCode. hashCode for B,rB is equal and different from A. Thats why I raised the question.

Comment: @articlestack You will need to override hashCode as well so it conforms to the contract for equals *and* hashCode

Comment: If the hashcodes for `A` and `B` are different then they will (probably) end up in different buckets in the `HashMap`, which means that `equals` will not be called. If `A.equals(B)` but `A.hashCode() != B.hashCode()` (i.e. equals is not consistent with hashCode) then you will see strange behaviour.

Comment: @Cameron Skinner, Correct me if I am wrong. HashMap compares by hashCode first. If it matches then only it uses equals() for comparision. While IdentityHashMap use hashCode only for comparing keys.

Comment: @articlestack: Not quite. `HashMap` compares by `hashCode`, then by `equals`. `IdentityHashMap` compares by `System.identityHashCode`, then by `==`. Note the use of `System.identityHashCode` rather than the usual `hashCode` method for assigning keys to buckets. Remember that hash codes are not required to be unique. The only contract is that objects that are `equal` must return the same hash code. Objects that are not `equal` may or may not return different hash codes, but won't work very well in a `HashMap` if they don't.

Answer (score -1):

As you have said above, A != B, so in IdentityHashMap A and B aren't considered as the same thing. You've put A with value 1, and B with value 2 (which is then overriden by rB with 3). The output is just as expected.

Comment: The OP is saying that the behaviour with `HashMap` is unexpected, not with `IdentityHashMap`.